# Limit distribution of sample median

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to prove the next:

Let $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ be iid $U(0,1)$ random variables and consider the order statistics $U_{1,n}\leq U_{2,n}\leq\ldots\leq U_{n,n}.$ When $n$ is odd, the middle order statistic is the sample median. Then $$2(U_{n+1,2n+1}-\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{2n}$$ has a limit distribution. What is it?

So, I'm trying to use Sheffé's lemma to prove the convergence.

Because such r.v. are uniform the density of $U_{n+1,2n+1}$ is $Beta(n+1,n+1).$ Then the density of $2(U_{n+1,2n+1}-\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{2n}$ is the density of such Beta evaluated in $\frac{x}{2\sqrt{2n}}+\frac{1}{2}$ multiplied by $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2n}}.$

I was utilizing Stirling approximation but I do not get any useful to calculate a limit. I don't think there is an easier form to prove this.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Your $Beta(n+1,n+1)$ has mean $\frac12$ and variance $\frac{1}{8n+12}$ so the scale and location adjusted form will have mean $0$ and variance $\frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{2n}}$, which tends to $1$ as $n$ increases.  For large $n$ it will be approximately normal in shape, and so the scale and location adjusted form will have the limit of a standard normal distribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general result that states that if $Y_n$ be the median of $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ which are iid with density $f$ and if $\mu$ be the population median, with $f$ continuous and positive at $\mu,$ then $\sqrt{n}(Y_n - \mu)$ converges in distribution to the Normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1/4f(\mu)^2.$

For your problem, the distribution $U(0,1)$ is symmetric about $1/2,$ so $\mu=1/2$ and $f(\mu) = 1.$ Hence,
$\sqrt{2n+1} \left(U_{n+1, 2n+1} - 1/2\right)$ will converge in distribution to $N(0, 1/4).$ Thus, it follows that
$2\sqrt{2n} \left(U_{n+1, 2n+1} - 1/2\right)$ will converge in distribution to $N(0, 1).$

For a proof of the general result I stated above, you may consult the following link:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.wustl.edu/~russw/s11.math494/CLT_medians.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjA7MzSpfPmAhVkzTgGHXyMChsQFjAMegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw1KheUMCWw61WtYZQCca6oh

Comment: Nice! Thanks @Aditya Ghosh.